# PHPStan & WordPress Plugin Boilerplate - Parameter #2 $callback of function add_filter expects callable(): mixed, array{mixed, mixed} given?

Tags: php, wordpress, phpstan

I started using PHPStan with the WordPress Plugin Boilerplate project that can be found [here](https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate/tree/master/plugin-name).

I am stuck in the class-plugin-name-loader.php file validation

I solved these errors:

```
33 - Property Plugin_Name_Loader::$actions type has no value type specified in iterable type array.

42 - Property Plugin_Name_Loader::$filters type has no value type specified in iterable type array.
```

By replacing array with mixed[]

When I increase the rule level to **7**, these validation errors appear:

```
120 - Parameter #2 $callback of function add_filter expects callable(): mixed, array{mixed, mixed} given.
                                             
124 - Parameter #2 $callback of function add_action expects callable(): mixed, array{mixed, mixed} given.
```

How do I fix this error?

My code relative to class-plugin-name-loader.php file:

```
/**
 * Register all actions and filters for the plugin
 *
 * @link       http://example.com
 * @since      1.0.0
 *
 * @package    Plugin_Name
 * @subpackage Plugin_Name/includes
 */

/**
 * Register all actions and filters for the plugin.
 *
 * Maintain a list of all hooks that are registered throughout
 * the plugin, and register them with the WordPress API. Call the
 * run function to execute the list of actions and filters.
 *
 * @package    Plugin_Name
 * @subpackage Plugin_Name/includes
 * @author     Your Name <email@example.com>
 */
class Plugin_Name_Loader {

    /**
     * The array of actions registered with WordPress.
     *
     * @since    1.0.0
     * @access   protected
     * @var      mixed[]    $actions    The actions registered with WordPress to fire when the plugin loads.
     */
    protected $actions;

    /**
     * The array of filters registered with WordPress.
     *
     * @since    1.0.0
     * @access   protected
     * @var      mixed[]    $filters    The filters registered with WordPress to fire when the plugin loads.
     */
    protected $filters;

    /**
     * Initialize the collections used to maintain the actions and filters.
     *
     * @since    1.0.0
     */
    public function __construct() {

        $this->actions = array();
        $this->filters = array();

    }

    /**
     * Add a new action to the collection to be registered with WordPress.
     *
     * @since    1.0.0
     * @param    string               $hook             The name of the WordPress action that is being registered.
     * @param    object               $component        A reference to the instance of the object on which the action is defined.
     * @param    string               $callback         The name of the function definition on the $component.
     * @param    int                  $priority         Optional. The priority at which the function should be fired. Default is 10.
     * @param    int                  $accepted_args    Optional. The number of arguments that should be passed to the $callback. Default is 1.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function add_action( $hook, $component, $callback, $priority = 10, $accepted_args = 1 ) {
        $this->actions = $this->add( $this->actions, $hook, $component, $callback, $priority, $accepted_args );
    }

    /**
     * Add a new filter to the collection to be registered with WordPress.
     *
     * @since    1.0.0
     * @param    string               $hook             The name of the WordPress filter that is being registered.
     * @param    object               $component        A reference to the instance of the object on which the filter is defined.
     * @param    string               $callback         The name of the function definition on the $component.
     * @param    int                  $priority         Optional. The priority at which the function should be fired. Default is 10.
     * @param    int                  $accepted_args    Optional. The number of arguments that should be passed to the $callback. Default is 1
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function add_filter( $hook, $component, $callback, $priority = 10, $accepted_args = 1 ) {
        $this->filters = $this->add( $this->filters, $hook, $component, $callback, $priority, $accepted_args );
    }

    /**
     * A utility function that is used to register the actions and hooks into a single
     * collection.
     *
     * @since    1.0.0
     * @access   private
     * @param    mixed[]                $hooks            The collection of hooks that is being registered (that is, actions or filters).
     * @param    string               $hook             The name of the WordPress filter that is being registered.
     * @param    object               $component        A reference to the instance of the object on which the filter is defined.
     * @param    string               $callback         The name of the function definition on the $component.
     * @param    int                  $priority         The priority at which the function should be fired.
     * @param    int                  $accepted_args    The number of arguments that should be passed to the $callback.
     * @return   mixed[]                                  The collection of actions and filters registered with WordPress.
     */
    private function add( $hooks, $hook, $component, $callback, $priority, $accepted_args ) {

        $hooks[] = array(
            'hook'          => $hook,
            'component'     => $component,
            'callback'      => $callback,
            'priority'      => $priority,
            'accepted_args' => $accepted_args
        );

        return $hooks;

    }

    /**
     * Register the filters and actions with WordPress.
     *
     * @since    1.0.0
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run() {

        foreach ( $this->filters as $hook ) {
            add_filter( $hook['hook'], array( $hook['component'], $hook['callback'] ), $hook['priority'], $hook['accepted_args'] );
        }

        foreach ( $this->actions as $hook ) {
            add_action( $hook['hook'], array( $hook['component'], $hook['callback'] ), $hook['priority'], $hook['accepted_args'] );
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Trying to use a linter against wordpress is like trying to use sandpaper against water

Comment: Instead of linking to a repository, please add the relevant code to the question itself as text.

Answer (score 0):

`array{mixed, mixed}` is not guaranteed to be a callable. Use a more specific type. Here's the guide: https://phpstan.org/writing-php-code/phpdoc-types

You can look into callables and array shapes specifically.